# C++ build error in GCC (MoSync) due to std::pair

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, mosync

I'm using MoSync IDE to build my C++ code for mobile platform. Initially the C++ code was built separately by Visual Studio 2010 without any problems. But when I used MoSync IDE to rebuild the C++ code, it generated some error message. My C++ code uses STL library like std::pair and std::vector classes. Below is the code that was compiled as error in MoSync IDE. MoSync uses GCC 3.4.6. So I assume this is caused by the GCC compiler.

```
template<typename T>
vector< pair<T, int> > histogram(const vector<T>& x, int numBins)
{
    T maxVal, minVal, range, delta, leftEdge, rightEdge;
    int i, dummyIdx;
    vector<T>::iterator pt;
    vector< pair<T, int> > counts(numBins, make_pair(T(), 0));
    vector<T> y(x);

//other code ...

}
```

The error message is:

**error: expected `;' before "pt" (line 6)**

This template function calculates histogram given the input vector x and numBins, and it returns "counts" as the pair of (bins, counts). Originally I compiled this C++ code in Visual Studio 2010 without any errors. But GCC in MoSync IDE gave me this error message. So this baffles me a lot why this fails to build in GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<T>::iterator` is dependent type so you need to use `typename`:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator pt;
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. So why doesn't VS2010 flag this as an error while GCC considers this as an error?

Comment: @tonga: Because Visual Studio's default mode is not a strict conformance mode. TBH, I am not sure if the non-extensions mode will reject it either.